# How can I stop the OpenFileDialog in Office from displaying my Network computers?

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, active-directory, windows-terminal-services, microsoft-office

We have a Windows Server 2008 running Terminal Services. Users typically use the Drop Down menu at the top of the dialog to select a location to open/save their file. The problem is that by default the DropDown expands the first level item under Desktop, and that item happens to be Network, so the entire application freezes for a minute or two (sometimes they get timeout errors, other times it will load after a minute or two)

Is there a way to NOT show my Network places in the Open/Save dialog of Office products?

- Server is Windows Server 2010 R2
- Office program is Office 2003 Professional
- The path is Desktop\Network, even though the Network icon doesn't show up on their desktop
- Active Directory polices are in place to restrict what the users can access. On an admin account which can access everything, the top item in the Desktop list is Computer (not Network), so there is no delay in loading the drop down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the Office 2003 administrative templates (http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=9035). You can use these to configure group policies that will disable access to network places.